# How to draw points on a panel with an image

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a panel named dPanel. I set the the backgroundImage of that panel with an image named dImage.Now I want to draw points on the panel, in other words I want to color the panel by using mouse.I want to be able to save the drawing and the image together later. My codes do this but the picture lights up during drawing and its very slow.Here is my code:

```
 private void drawP_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!drawbool)
        {
            dStartPoint = e.Location;
            drawbool = true;
        }
        drawP.Invalidate();
    }
 private void drawP_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (drawbool)
        {
            dStartPoint = e.Location;
            drawP.Invalidate();
        }
    }
 private void drawP_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (drawbool)
        {
            drawbool = false;
        }
    }
  private void drawP_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (drawbool)
        {
            int dStartX = dStartPoint.X;
            int dStartY = dStartPoint.Y;
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(dP, dStartX, dStartY, 2, 2);
            Bitmap dPPB = new Bitmap(drawP.Width, drawP.Height);
            drawP.DrawToBitmap(dPPB, new Rectangle(0, 0, drawP.Width, drawP.Height));
            drawP.BackgroundImage = (Image)dPPB;
        }
    }
```

Whani's the solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, any how you want to draw a shape like rectangle, circle etc or simply one dot on the image?

Comment: I want to draw sevral dots by draging mouse on the panel

Comment: No, first you get a clear idea about drawing in WinForms. You can draw a line by draging in winforms with C#, but not a dot. How can you draw dots by draging.

Comment: I can draw a FillEllipse ( 2 width and 2 height) whenever the pain event occurs.bit I need not to loose my last painting(last ellipse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this great example about drawing on panel: [Painting on a Panel](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/PanelPainting.aspx).

Later you can save your drawing just by invoking panel's method **DrawToBitmap**.

Comment: The article helped me a lot.I used all the codes provided in it.Thanks a lot